# Integrate gives wrong results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

```
Integrate[a/(Sin[t]^2 + a^2), {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

$$\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{a}{a^2+\sin ^2(t)} \, dt$$

gives $0$

This cannot be true. What is going on?

If I insert a number into `a`, it gives a reasonable result:

```
NIntegrate[2/(Sin[t]^2 + 4), {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

give `2.80993`

Comment: Note `Integrate` itself gets it right if you give `a` a value,(  `2 Pi/Sqrt[5]` here )

Comment: [A relevant link.](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$Version

(*
Out[228]= "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 7, 2011)"
*)
```

The result provided by *Mathematica* is correct:

```
Integrate[a/(a^2 + Sin[t]^2), {t, 0, 2 π}]

(*
Out[213]= (2 π)/(Sqrt[1 + 1/a^2] a)
*)
```

Now the same procedure as "always" which "explains" the zero result.
The indefinite integral is

```
Integrate[a/(a^2 + Sin[t]^2), t]

(*
Out[214]= ArcTan[(Sqrt[1 + a^2] Tan[t])/a]/Sqrt[1 + a^2]
*)
```

This result is not continuous for real `a`.
In this graph we can see the jumps as well as the necessary additional terms to restore continuity.

The jump must be determined by taking (directed) limits. Assuming first $a>0$ gives

```
Simplify[Limit[ArcTan[(Sqrt[1 + a^2] Tan[t])/a]/Sqrt[1 + a^2], 
   t -> π/2, Direction -> +1], a > 0] - 
 Simplify[Limit[ArcTan[(Sqrt[1 + a^2] Tan[t])/a]/Sqrt[1 + a^2], 
   t -> π/2, Direction -> -1], a > 0]

(*
Out[408]= π/Sqrt[1 + a^2]
*)
```

and therefore

```
With[{a = 1/2}, 
 Plot[{ArcTan[(Sqrt[1 + a^2] Tan[t])/a]/Sqrt[1 + a^2], 
   ArcTan[(Sqrt[1 + a^2] Tan[t])/a]/Sqrt[1 + a^2] + π/Sqrt[1 + a^2], 
   ArcTan[(Sqrt[1 + a^2] Tan[t])/a]/Sqrt[1 + a^2] + (2 π)/Sqrt[
    1 + a^2]}, {t, 0, 2 π}]]
```

[image: 150601_plot_int.jpg]

The blue (lower) curve is the original antiderivative, the red (middle) curve has `π/Sqrt[1+a^2]` added, and is the continiuous continuation between `π/2` and `3π/2`, finally the brown (upper) curve does it for the rest adding again the same amount `π/Sqrt[1+a^2]`.

Hence taking the difference of the antiderivative at the endpoints according to the fundamental theorem of calculus would lead to zero on the blue curve, and is only correct for the continuous version leading to the correct result given in the beginning.

**EDIT #1**

The case $a<0$ need not be discussed separately because of the (anti)symmetry of the integral.

Note that because the antiderivative vanishes at both ends the integral is equal to the "total" jump, which here is twice the amount of the jump at $\pi/2$.

This and other examples point to the (tentative) rule: if the result of `Integrate[]` is zero despite the fact that the integrand is positive check for jumps and calculate them using the directed Limits. The integral will then be the sum of the jumps over the whole interval.

Answer (score 6):

The result zero does not look correct. But you can get the correct result by using  `PrincipalValue -> True`

```
r = Integrate[a/(Sin[t]^2 + a^2), {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

now `r /. a -> 2.0` gives the value you show

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The original answer, without `PrincipalValue -> True` gives

```
   r = Integrate[a/(Sin[t]^2 + a^2), t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maple gets this right, but with a sign added:

[image: Maple result]

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica 10.1 seems to have fixed this bug:

[image: answer from 10.1]

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed the result in both *Mathematica* 9 and 10 on Linux.

Using an assumption seems to work:

```
Integrate[a/(Sin[t]^2 + a^2), {t, 0, 2 π}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

> ```
> (2 π)/Sqrt[1 + a^2]
> ```

which agrees with `NIntegrate`.

I'm not sure about the source of the discrepancy though. It could be a bug or the way the assumptions are made, i.e. by default `a` is considered complex, so either the integral is zero for complex `a` (didn't do the calcs) or `Integrate` gets confused somehow.

In any case, always remember to play around with the assumptions and numerically test the results.

Cheers

Comment: The answer about adding `PrincipalValue` also makes me suspect that the problem is `a` is treated as a complex number. So rather than `a > 0`, `ElementQ[a, Reals]` is probably sufficient :)

Comment: @CompuChip how does $a$ being complex validate Mathematica output? The integral is still non-zero for e.g. $a=1+3i$.

Answer (score 2):

Another, in my opinion simpler, alternative is to use the symmetry.

```
4 Integrate[a/(a^2 + Sin[t]^2), {t, 0, π/2}]

(* (2 π)/(Sqrt[1 + 1/a^2] a) *)
```

without additional assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but consider the following function:

$$f_c(a,x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+a^2}}\left(x+\arctan\left(\frac{\sin\,x\cos\,x}{a^2+a\sqrt{1+a^2}+\sin^2 x}\right)\right)$$

You can verify the following identity in *Mathematica*:

```
fc[a_, x_] := (x + ArcTan[(Sin[x] Cos[x])/(a^2 + a Sqrt[1 + a^2] + Sin[x]^2)])/Sqrt[1 + a^2]
D[fc[a, x], x] == a/(a^2 + Sin[x]^2) // Simplify
   True
```

Compare this with the antiderivative produced by `Integrate[]`:

```
f[a_, x_] = Integrate[a/(a^2 + Sin[x]^2), x]
With[{a = 1/2}, Plot[{f[a, x], fc[a, x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue}]]
```

[image: two different antiderivatives]

and we see that $f_c(a,x)$ is continuous over $[0,2\pi]$, while $f(a,x)$ is not. Thus, $f(a,x)$ is not suitable for computing the definite integral through the FTC. But, if you use $f_c(a,x)$,

```
fc[a, 2 π] - fc[a, 0]
  2 π/Sqrt[1 + a^2]
```

Again, see [O. Pavlyk's blog entry](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) for more details.